# I can enter the inputs but I'm not able to see the output when I run my code (CTRL+F5) in C++ in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iostream

> I can enter the inputs but I'm not able to see the output when I run my code (CTRL+F5) in C++ in visual studio 2017. This code is written to overload the operator *, ">>" & "<<" through the friend functions. one constructor initializes the vector elements to zero while the other constructor is used to initialize the elements of vector through the array.

### My code is as below:

```
 //vector.h

#pragma once
const int SIZE = 3;
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class vector
{
    int v[SIZE];
public:
    vector();
    vector(int *x);
    friend vector operator *(vector a, int b);
    friend vector operator *(int b,vector a);
    friend istream & operator >>(istream &input, vector &x);
    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &output, vector &y);

};

    //vector.cpp

#include "vector.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



vector::vector()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        v[i] = 0;

}
vector::vector(int *x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        v[i] = x[i];

}
vector operator *(vector a, int b) {
    vector temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        temp.v[i] = a.v[i]*b;
    return temp;


}
vector operator *(int a, vector b) {
    vector temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        temp.v[i] = a * b.v[i];
    return temp;
}
istream & operator >>(istream &input, vector &x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        input >> x.v[i];
    return (input);


}
ostream & operator <<(ostream &output, vector &y) {
    output << "(" << y.v[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
        output <<","<< y.v[i];
    output << ")";
    return (output);

}

    //main.cpp

#include "vector.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int x[SIZE] = { 2,4,6 };
int main() {

    vector m;   
    vector v2 = x;
    cout << "Enter the elements of vector m:" << "\n";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\n";
    vector m1, m2;
    m1 = m * 2;
    m2 = 2 * v2;
    cout << "m= "<<m<<"\n"; 
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "m1= " << m1 << "\n";
    cout << "m2= " << m2 << "\n";
    cin.get();

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: It works for me. The program asks for input and I see output. Whatever problem you are having it's not caused by the code. It might help to say what input you are using, and exactly what you do see (if anything).

Comment: I press CTRL+F5 then a black window appears. I'm giving the inputs as 10, 20 and 30 by pressing enter keys after each input number. After I enter the 3rd number 30, the black screen disappear in a flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your linker settings are incorrect. Go to menu item Project/Properties. Then in the dialog find Configuration Properties/Linker/System/Subsystem and make sure it says `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`.

Evgeny is correct `cin.get()` is not guaranteed to halt your program because there are still characters waiting to be read from `cin` that are left over from previous reads.

Comment: Thanks for your response John!

For me the 'Subsystem' option was empty. I changed that to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) as suggested by you but still the issue could not got resolved.

But,then, I changed the processor option from x86 (32 bit) to x64(64 bit) and It worked!!
Not sure though, how it worked? any idea?

Comment: @DeepakSingh That's surprising, I wonder if the program didn't rebuild properly after the first change. Maybe try changing it back to x86 and still if it still works.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answers John.
I switched between processor options and it's working for both x86 and x64. 
Closing the loop with the conclusion that the issue was with the Linker setting.
A big Thank you John!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes you must enter 3 number. If you enter less numbers you see no output.

Some comments:

Your cin.get() doesn't stop execution.
Using std (like using namespace std) and definition own vector class - it's very bad idea.

Comment: I press CTRL+F5 then a black window appears. I'm giving the inputs as 10, 20 and 30 by pressing enter keys after each input number. After I enter the 3rd number 30, the black screen disappear in a flash.
I didn't get your comments, could you please elaborate a bit.